# Interiors and Closure

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove

$int(\overline S)\subset \overline {S \cap int(\overline S)}$

I would like some hints(*Only hints I dont want the solution)*

Comment: My intuition tells me that the RHS is the closure of $S$.

Comment: No its not think if S= middle thirds cantor set.

Comment: Yeah you are right, possibly both sides are $\emptyset$ or perhaps something more wired (I can't think of). Is proof by case plausible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in\text{int}(\overline S)$.  Let $x\in U$ open.  You need to show $U\cap(S\cap\text{int}(\overline S))\not=\emptyset$.  Show you can assume $U\subseteq\text{int}(\overline S)$.  You know $U\cap\overline S\not=\emptyset$.  So you have to show $U\cap S\not=\emptyset$.  So you have to show $U\subseteq\text{int}(\overline S)$ implies $U\cap \overline S\not=\emptyset$.

Comment: I am accepting your answer but in the future please avoid sketching the solution explicitly when only hints have been requested :)

Comment: Sorry, I thought this is what you wanted, it's not an explicit solution, but a sketch you'd have to fill in several details.

Comment: The first three sentences are just a re-statement of the problem.  Sentence 4 is a hint.  Sentence five is a hint.  Sentence six is a hint.